# Macro result, date day and month sometimes swapped

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, swap

I programmed a macro to search for the empty cells and copy de content of the previous row on them.
It works okay, but one of the copied columns contains a date, and in some cells it's not properly copied, swapping day and month.

Someone can help me?. I'm new into this.

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyDataFromPreviosRow()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Disable ScreeUpdating for faster speed
Dim c As Range 'Defining a counter
Dim last_row As Integer 'Defining a variable to store last filled row number

    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row with contents
    
    For Each c In Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(last_row, 1))
        If c.Value = "" Then 'If the row is empty
            c.EntireRow.Columns("A:E").Value = c.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Columns("A:E").Value 'Copy the values of the columns A to C from the previous row to the current row
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Enable ScreenUpdating

End Sub
```

I tried to Change the column type to Date, and to store the value in a date variable but no result.
I expect the values to be exactly the same as they are in the origin row.

Comment: What is the source of the Dates?  If they originated in a CSV or Text file, especially if that file was **opened** in Excel, they may be incorrect at that point.  **Import** the file instead, using either Power Query or the legacy import wizard, so the date format in that csv file can be properly set.  There are other issues with your macro, but I don't believe they would cause this problem.

Comment: If you want the values to **appear** ***exactly the same*** as in the original column, then, after ensuring the column is wide enough to display everything (no narrow cells displaying `###...`), copy the Text property of the cell and paste it into a text-formatted column.

Comment: The cause of your issue is that those "dates" you copy are no dates but text. And when you copy them Excel sees "oh that looks like a date, I can try to interpert that" and then it messes it up. The actual question here is why are those dates no real numeric dates and how to convert them into numeric dates. The problem clearly lies in the source of that data and not in the macro itself. Those "texts looking like dates" need to be converted into real numeric dates (by splitting them apart and using `DateSerial` to build a numeric date).

Comment: Thank you for your help. By now, I solved it changing the way I was copying the cells, and using Copy and PasteSpecial, but that is much slower. The origin file is an xls obtained from a Web Application, and is in "General" Format. I tried to convert that column into Date but that didn't solve the problem either. I will search info about Dateserial and I will tell you. Thank you very much for your interest!